# Logout user while preserving cart contents

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, session

When user leaves checkout funnel I need to logout him while preserving his cart contents (so the just logged out user as a guest would see all cart items that he had in a cart when he was logged in). How can I achieve that?

Comment: what is mean by " logout him while preserving his cart contents"?

Comment: So all items that were in cart when he was loggen in remains there after logout (for guest user)

Answer (score 1):

The `Mage_Checkout` module declares an observer on `customer_logout` event which executes the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Observer::unsetAll()` method which in turn calls `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::unsetAll()` whose body follows:

```
public function unsetAll()
{
    parent::unsetAll();
    $this->_quote = null;
}
```

As you see, it is responsible for clearing all data from session, including the quote.

You could be tempted to disable the event observer but I discourage it because it is necessary to clear private data from session.

A better approach could be that of registering your own observer on the same event and call the `preserveQuote()` method which copies the quote of the logging-out customer to the already emptied (by the core observer) session as show below:

```
public function preserveQuote($observer)
{
    $customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($observer->getCustomer());
    $currentQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $currentQuote->merge($customerQuote);
}
```

Do your tests because I didn't examine if there can be drawbacks to this solution.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Under system > configuration > customers > persistent shopping cart you can enable the persistent shopping cart feature, and make your settings accordingly for how long to keep items in the customer's cart.